# emphasise in bold text when it is in a certain position on screen, jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make a small alarm/timer/stopwatch app in Kotlin and I am using jetpack compose.
the composable for the time selector is this

```
@Composable
fun Timer(durationsList: List<String>, sizeOfTimer: Int) {
    var parentPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    var centeredTextPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    val timerState = rememberLazyListState()

    Box(modifier = Modifier.size(sizeOfTimer.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.background(MyColor.neutralGrey.color).fillMaxWidth()
                .size((sizeOfTimer / 8).dp)
                .onGloballyPositioned { parentPosition = it.positionInParent() }
        ) {}
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MyColor.LighterGray.copy(0.1f))
                .size(sizeOfTimer.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 4.dp)
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    centeredTextPosition = it.positionInParent()
                },
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            state = timerState,
            flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState = timerState)
        ) {
            items(durationsList) { index ->
                Box {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp, 8.dp),
                            text = index,
                            fontSize = 20.sp
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it is looking like this :[image]
list scrolled a bit : [image]

I have a transparent Column overlayed over a light grey box( am not sure if this is the best way to do this) I want to make the time value that overlaps with the grey box in the middle to become emphasized in bold while the other values stay how they are now. I would like also to be able to recover that value that is overlapping with the box so I can use it to start my count function for the timer.
I am not completely sure how wouldd the modifier onGlobalPositioning work here, positionInWindow vs positionInParent vs positionInRoot, I don't know how to use them with 2 compostables where one is not inside the other but lays over it. As you see, I gave it some tries but it is not successful, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to figure out how your `centeredTextPosition` translates to a selected item. Once that's done, simply add a `SpanStyle(Bold)` to the `Text` for that item.